# using MIN within WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to use `MIN` within the `WHERE` clause?

I'm trying to insert a subquery into one of my scripts and the subquery I set up was originally its own query that used something like this:

```
SELECT
   person, MIN(date)
FROM
   orders
WHERE
   date > "1/1/2015" and date < "1/31/2015"
GROUP BY
   person
```

This was to ensure the FIRST record, the earliest record, was the return value. Using `ORDER BY ASC LIMIT 1` didnt work. I want to replicate this so that I can say:

```
WHERE
   otherPersons IN (
      SELECT
         person, MIN(date)
      FROM
         orders
      WHERE
         date > "1/1/2015" and date < "1/31/2015"
    )
      GROUP BY
        person
```

Meaning, otherPersons has to be in Person, but only those persons whose earliest date falls within  my date spread. I understand this is impossible as a subquery can only have 1 column selected.

I'm new to SQL, sorry for the simplicity of the question.

Comment: Nope.  That's why SQL has the `having` clause.

Comment: How would I replicate this effect in the `having` clause?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do -- sample data and expected results would be helpful.  Looks like you're missing the `group by` clause.  And you can't select multiple fields with `in` like that.

Comment: In my question I said "Meaning, otherPersons has to be in Person, but only those persons whose earliest date falls within my date spread. I understand this is impossible as a subquery can only have 1 column selected." which I think responds to both of your points.

Comment: Edited to include the `group by` clause

Comment: This is incorrect _"I understand this is impossible as a subquery can only have 1 column selected."_

Comment: "And you can't select multiple fields with in like that." Answer from: segeddes. Is that incorrect?

Comment: I am guessing sgeddes meant you can't do `a in (SELECT x, y FROM...` you need to have a matching field count, such as `(a,b) in (SELECT x, y FROM...`; similarly this is invalid `(1,2) IN (1, 2, 3)` but I think this is fine `(1, 2) IN ((1, 3), (2, 5), (6,12))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need only one

```
WHERE
   (otherPersons, date) IN (
      SELECT
         person, MIN(date)
      FROM
         orders
      WHERE
         date > "1/1/2015" and date < "1/31/2015"
      GROUP BY
        person
    )
      GROUP BY
        person
```

This is the same as a join with two clauses

```
JOIN  (
      SELECT
         person, MIN(date) as mindate
      FROM
         orders
      WHERE
         date > "1/1/2015" and date < "1/31/2015"
      GROUP BY
        person
    ) sub ON otherPersons = sub.person and date = sub.mindate
```

Comment: This is beautiful. I was under the impression the WHERE IN was more restrictive in a subquery. Thanks for clearing this up. Very very helpful.

Comment: @JosephErickson it is likely that the `JOIN` version will perform much better than the `WHERE` one; subqueries in `WHERE` clauses are _rarely_ better than an equivalent `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
SELECT
     person, MIN(date) as min_date -- field alias
  FROM
     orders
  WHERE         date > "1/1/2015" and date < "1/31/2015"
 HAVING Min(Date) > "xx/xx/xxxx"
```

you can field alias instead of `MIN(DATE)` in `MySQL`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too ambiguous, so let me throw a couple sql and descriptions to see if one of these matches what you are looking for.

First, I am looking for all persons who had an order on the same minimum date within the time period in question

```
select 
      o.person,
      o.date
   from
      orders o
         JOIN ( select min(date) minDate
                   from orders
                   where date "1/1/2015" 
                     and date < "1/31/2015" ) dateOnly
            on o.date = dateOnly.minDate
```

Second, looking for ALL persons who placed an order within the time period in question AND want their OWN minimum order date.  Person "A" could buy on Jan 1, but Person "B" buys on Jan 12, Person "C" on Jan 14.  You would want all people with their date.

```
select 
      o.person,
      o.date
   from
      orders o
         JOIN ( select person, min(date) minDate
                   from orders
                   where date "1/1/2015" 
                     and date < "1/31/2015" 
                   group by person ) personDate
            on o.person = personDate.person
            AND o.date = personDate.minDate
```